# Magento: Change order of billing information in checkout

Tags: magento

The default Magento billing information style is like this

```
name Surname

adress

house number

city, zip code

country

telephone
```

i need to change it to

```
name surname

adress house number

city, zip code

country

telephone
```

but i cant seem to find the way to do this.

any thoughts? there's nothing in .phtml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the default skin with Magento?

In your `/app/design/frontend` folder you’ve probably a number of different packages (eg. base) and themese (e.g. default). In your admin area navigation to **System > Configuration > then click the ‘Design’ tab.** Here you’ll be able to see the current package and theme you’re using.

Magento has a system of inheritance so template files in your current package have priority over the Magento defaults (base/default). Therefore is suspect you have a `/app/design/frontend/<<PACAKGE>>/<<THEME>>/template/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

**EDIT**

Sorry to give wrong way as you want alternate way is very simple to manage with admin

just go to System -> configuration -> customer -> customer configuration -> select HTML block to manage

[image]

just change your order of fields.

please see above image so you have good idea on that, but i it will change for all display address in system.

so if you want go with this solution you can, and if you wish to customize then create you template file with use of `<?php echo $this->getBilling() ?>`  array to print.

it comes from `frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml`

hope you understand my scenario.

Comment: those are input fields... after you click "continue" on the right you can see this info.  all those lines have <br /> at the end and i need to remove some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the config.xml of the Sales module.

You'll see templates that you can modify